# Sending values from one page to another using sessions

Tags: asp.net

I am sending values from send page to receive page using sessions, its working fine but the problem is I remember the **URL** and i directly run receive  page its shows previous information but it's invalid is it....?

If end user directly visit receive page i need to restrict or give some message something like that

How can i overcome this problem..............

**This is my code**

**send.aspx.cs**

```
protected void gv_rowcommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        GridViewRow grow = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource)).NamingContainer;

        Session["c"] = grow.Cells[0].Text;
        Session["s"] = grow.Cells[1].Text;
        Session["e"] = grow.Cells[2].Text;
        Session["t"] = grow.Cells[3].Text;
        Session["a"] = grow.Cells[4].Text;
        Response.Redirect("confirmation.aspx");

    }   
}
```

**confirmation.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblgetcourse.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["c"]);
    lblgetstartdate.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["s"]);
    lblgetenddate.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["e"]);
    lblgettimings.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["t"]);
    lblgetamount.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["a"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have displayed the values on the confirmation page you could remove them from the Session.

```
Session.Remove("c");
...
```

This will ensure that the confirmation page will always display *fresh* values coming from the `send.aspx` page. You could also check for the presence of those values in the session before displaying them.

Comment: Thank you it's working, suppose the end user directly visit confirmation.aspx page, without showing that page can we redirect to send.aspx page...?  because its invalid...

Comment: In this case you will check if the Session contains the value before using it and redirect him if it doesn't. Like this: `if (Session["c"] == null) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

On Confirmation Page, Fetch the Values from Session Variables an display them , then Clear Session variables just like: Session.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

You can check the referrer header :

`Request.UrlReferrer`

and see where the request comes from.

so your page_load will look like :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Request.UrlReferrer=='...') Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath == "~/send.aspx")
    {
        lblgetcourse.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["c"]);
        lblgetstartdate.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["s"]);
        lblgetenddate.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["e"]);
        lblgettimings.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["t"]);
        lblgetamount.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["a"]);
    }
    else
    {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Request.UraReferrer is not working.......... it shows " == canot be applied of type system.uri and string"

Comment: added it shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."